# i want my datagridview 1st n 2nd column to be fixed n remaining columns should be enter by user

Tags: c#, datagridview

|BrandName| ML       |  STOCK   |
|         |          |          |
|PEPSI    | 100      |          |
|         |          |          |
|LIMCA    | 200      |          |
|         |          |          |

I Want my DataGridView to look like above table.

and how to save the data after entering stock.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Frozen` property for each column of the `DataGridView`. You juste have to set it to `True`.

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView.Columns[1].Frozen = true;
```

Would've been pretty easy to Google up, don't you think?

Comment: i want brandname and ml field to be fixed same as like Msexcel.i am not able to fixed this two fields

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed". Do mean ReadOnly, or do you want them freezed when you scroll horizontally?

Comment: i want it to be in same place. for example when date changes stock should be empty and brandname and ml should be in same place